# BeautifulSoup を用いた、特定のli の内容の取得

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

次のようなタグの情報を取得したいと考えています。

```
<ul class="dtlTbl">
        <li data-locate="address"><dl>
                <dt>住所</dt> 
                </dl>
        </li>
        <li data-locate="tel"><dl>
                <dt>TEL</dt>
                </dl>
        </li>
</ul>
```

このタグから、次のようにli の内容をひとつづつ保存したいと考えています。
address = ["住所"]
tel = ["tel"]
このために、次のようなコードを書いています。

```
import requests
import bs4 
import pandas as pd 

resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

li_part = soup.find_all("ul", class_="dtlTbl")
address = li_part.find_all("li", data-locate="address")
```

しかし、次のようなエラーが出生じています。

```
 address = detail_part.find_all("li", data-locate="address")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

この問題について、解決方法を示唆して頂けますと、大変ありがたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

引用： [kondou.com - Beautiful Soup 4.2.0 Doc. 日本語訳 (2013-11-19最終更新)](http://kondou.com/BS4/)

```
HTML5の ‘data-*’ 属性など、いくつかの属性についてはキーワード引数として用いることができません。:

data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
しかし、これらの属性を辞書にして、キーワード引数 attrs として値を渡せばフィルタリングすることができます。:

data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
# [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
```

なので、やりたいことは下記になると思います。
`li_part.find_all("li", attrs={"data-locate": "address"})`

Comment: うまくいきました。出典も書いて頂きまして、大変助かります。